# Get device width in view (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to load different partial view based on device width and for that I am trying this line into view

```
@
{
   if(Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth<500)
   {
            /// load partial view accordingly
   }
   if(Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth>=500&&Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth<1000)
   {
            /// load partial view accordingly
   }
}
```

but I am always getting same value every time after re-sizing the screen of my emulated device.
Can any body tell me what wrong with this or suggest me right way to do same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$( window ).width();` *returns width of browser viewport* .

Comment: I can't do this using jquery. I am looking for c# code

Comment: why don't you set logic in script end and then call respective partial view via `RenderPartial` or `RenderAction` (just a advice) .

Comment: In other-way you can pass view-port size to controller from view (not preferred) .